# deploy JuJu charm on AWS without data storage

Tags: juju

Every time I deploy a charm from JuJu onto AWS, it creates the EC2 instance, but it also automatically attaches a 8GiB data volume to the instance.  I can't find documentation about how to configure the data volume.  Is there a way to not attach the data volume and how? Is there a way to specify the data volume size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the juju documentation for setting constraints
I don't believe that there is a way to deploy juju without a disk attached, however you can set the size of the node by setting the --constraints root-disk flag.